# Removed LVM swap partition, and now booting takes a lot of time because of errors

Tags: boot, swap, lvm

### Context

Originally I had the following partition structure

```
nvme0n1
├─nvme0n1p1             /boot/efi
└─nvme0n1p2
  ├─ubuntu--vg-root     /
  └─ubuntu--vg-swap_1   swap
```

Then I decided to remove the swap partition and use, instead, a swapfile. I created a file, called `mkswap /swapfile` on it, `swapoff -a` and then `swapon /swapfile`. I then edited `/etc/fstab` and changed the line

```
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1   none swap sw  0 0
```

to

```
/swapfile  none swap sw  0 0
```

Rebooting worked perfectly, so I opened `gparted` and deleted the swap partition to extend root (which I did instead using `lvexpand`), so my partitions look now (as for the command `lsblk`)

```
nvme0n1
├─nvme0n1p1             /boot/efi
└─nvme0n1p2
  └─ubuntu--vg-root     /
```

### The problem

I must have messed up here because now reboot takes al least 25 seconds (instead of 4) and it looks like it's pausing boot to look for swap partition, as the following message appears at least 5 times before booting normally

```
failed to find logical volume ubuntu-vg/swap_1
```

### What I've tried (according to what I've found online)

1. running `update-grub` (nowhere in `grub.cfg` is mentioned `swap_1`)
2. running `update-initramfs -u`
3. file `/etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume` doesn't exist, so nothing to change here
4. `lsblk` and `lvdisplay` only show the root partition

I'm afraid there must still be somewhere a notion of the swap partition in the LVM configuration, as I didn't use its commands to remove it, but I've found nowhere a place that lists `swap_1` as a partition (except for some files in `/etc/lvm/archive`, but I guess they aren't useful for me). I've even run a full disk search for the content `swap_1` in any file, but only error logs contained that work in text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, `update-initramfs -u` was not enough, as it did not update the current kernel initramfs (but instead used one of the other kernels I was not using) and kept using the old one with the old partition. The solution was to specify the kernel that was currently loaded

```
sudo update-initramfs -k $(uname -r) -u
```

(in doubt I've also added `RESUME=/swapfile` to `/etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume` which previously did not exist, so also that)

Comment: Or you can update all installed kernels at once by using `sudo update-initramfs -u -k all`